# Internet Explorer dom behaves differently in different environment

Tags: java, powershell

I have a powershell script which is like this

```
param(
   [string]$u,
   [string]$p
)

$username = $u
$password = $p

cd HKCU:\"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
set-itemproperty . ProxyEnable 1
$url = "https://ameriprisestage.service-now.com/"
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;

$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url);
while ($ie.ReadyState -ne 4 -or $ie.Busy)
{
     start-sleep -s 5;
}

 $ieFrame = $ie.Document.getElementById("gsft_main")

 if (($ieFrame -eq $null)) {
    "ieframe is null" | Out-File 'D:\\file.txt' -Append
    exit
 }

 $usrCtrl = $ie.Document.getElementById("user_name")
 if ($usrCtrl -eq $null) {
     " usrCtrl is null at 1" |Out-File 'D:\\file.txt' -Append
 }

 $usrCtrl = $ieFrame.document.getElementById("user_name")
 if ($usrCtrl -eq $null) {
     " usrCtrl is null at 2" |Out-File 'D:\\file.txt' -Append
 }

 $usrCtrl = $ieFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById("user_name")
 if ($usrCtrl -eq $null) {
     " usrCtrl is null at 3" |Out-File 'D:\\file.txt' -Append
 }

 $usrCtrl = $ieFrame.contentDocument.getElementById("user_name")
 if ($usrCtrl -eq $null) {
      " usrCtrl is null at 4" |Out-File 'D:\\file.txt' -Append
 }

 $usrCtrl = $ieFrame.getElementById("user_name")
 if ($usrCtrl -eq $null) {
    " usrCtrl is null at 5" |Out-File 'D:\\file.txt' -Append
  }

 $usrCtrl.value=$username
 $pass=$ieFrame.contentWindow.Document.getElementById("user_password").value=$password
 $buttn=$ieFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById("sysverb_login").click()
```

when i run this code from powershell ISE I get usrCtrl not null at 3 and 5. but when i invoke the same code from java program i get usrCtrl is null at 1, 2,3 4 and 5.

I can't figure out what is happening. can someone help me ..

Thanks
Sujith

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
cd HKCU:\"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
```

to

```
cd "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
```

AND this:

```
D:\\file.txt
```

to

```
D:\file.txt
```